# how to compensate for the gap in grid columns size?

Tags: css, css-grid

I think this is a common problem but still can't find an answer. Please take a look to the fiddle:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 20%;
  gap: 2em;
  background-color: rgba(250, 0, 0, .2);
}

.column {
  background-color: rgba(50, 0, 250, .2);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column">slide 1</div>
  <div class="column">slide 2</div>
  <div class="column">slide 3</div>
  <div class="column">slide 4</div>
  <div class="column">slide 5</div>
  <div class="column">slide 6</div>
</div>
```

I've got an x columns 'carousel' grid. I want that only 5 columns (for example) are visible, and they take all the available space. The remaining columns should be visible only on scroll. Therefore, columns size should be 20%. When I add the gap, the Grid is adding to the columns width instead of compensate their width. So I end up with the last of the 5 elements not being fully visible.

It's a really common issue I think, and maybe I could adjust cols witdh with calc(). But this is something that bugs me a bit, it feels really strange that there are no other faster solutions. There must be something better. So I'm asking here :)

Comment: Can't think of one but `calc` would seem to be the optimal solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Using calc(), this can be a solution:

```css
body{ margin: 0; }

.grid{
  --cols: 5;
  --gaps: calc(var(--cols) - 1);
  --gap: 2em;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: calc((100% - var(--gap) * var(--gaps)) / var(--cols));
  gap: var(--gap);
  
  background-color: rgba(250, 0, 0, .2);
}

.column{
  background-color: rgba(50, 0, 250, .2);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column">slide 1</div>
  <div class="column">slide 2</div>
  <div class="column">slide 3</div>
  <div class="column">slide 4</div>
  <div class="column">slide 5</div>
  <div class="column">slide 6</div>
</div>
```